# An error occured: ArtisanLambdaFunction - Unzipped size must be smaller than 220606645 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 4000

Tags: laravel, aws-lambda, serverless, bref

I was trying to deploy my Laravel application to AWS Lambda using Bref.
I tried to exclude almost all the images, videos and still I am getting

```
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
An error occurred: ArtisanLambdaFunction - Resource handler returned message: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 235311048 bytes (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400 ...
```

My serverless.yml file is

```
service: my-laravel-application

provider:
    name: aws
    # The AWS region in which to deploy (us-east-1 is the default)
    region: eu-west-1
    # The stage of the application, e.g. dev, production, staging… ('dev' is the default)
    stage: dev
    runtime: provided.al2

package:
    individually: true
    # Directories to exclude from deployment
    exclude:
        - node_modules/**
        - public/storage/**
        - resources/assets/**
        - storage/**
        - tests/**
        - public/images/**
        - public/uploads/**
        - public/videos/**

functions:
    # This function runs the Laravel website/API
    web:
        handler: public/index.php
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-74-fpm}
        events:
            -   httpApi: '*'
    # This function lets us run artisan commands in Lambda
    artisan:
        handler: artisan
        timeout: 120 # in seconds
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-74} # PHP
            - ${bref:layer.console} # The "console" layer

 plugins:  
    # We need to include the Bref plugin
    - ./vendor/bref/bref
```

I tried to exclude almost all the assets from zip. Still, I am getting the same error.
While zipping, the total size of my application is 119.4 MB only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by adding all public assets to exclude list and hence reduced the size of zip file to 43 MB.

While extracting the zip, the total size of unzipped is less than 220606645 bytes

Then ,

1. upload all the public folder files and folders to S3
2. Add ASSET_URL in env
3. use asset() function where ever we try to access the files from S3